# How to create a column of a specific type?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How would I add a column to a Select and have that column be of a specific type.

For example
Select Company, City, Dues, 0 As NewColumn1, 123.12 As NewColumn2
But I want NewColumn1 to be of type bit, and NewColumn2 to be of type Real

Oh, I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **CAST**

```
Select  Company,    
        City, 
        Dues, 
        CAST(0 AS BIT) As NewColumn1, 
        CAST(123.12 AS REAL As NewColumn2 
FROM    @Table
```

Have a look at [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) .